# C - System V - remove shared memory segment

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I'm using shared memory with System V IPC. I create segments using keys with the following command:

```
shmid1 = shmget(key1,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);
```

now, I'm trying to close/remove the shared memory segment.

I'm using the following command to verify it's existence:

```
sm_id = shmget(roomNumber, 1024, IPC_EXCL | 0666);
```

and I need it to have value `-1` or similar if program is interrupted. So I need to remove the segment before my program is interrupted. How can I achieve this? I read about `ipcrm` but not sure how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to remove a memory segment. `ipcrm` is a command-line tool, and if you want to call it programmatically, you should use `shmctl`. If you try to be more specific than 'not sure how to use it' a more tailored answer could be provided.

Comment: @SergeyA Could you please show me how do I close my memory segment using shmctl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow-up to the comments which shows how to remark shared memory segment for destruction:

```
shmid1 = shmget(key1,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);
...
shmctl(shmid1, IPC_RMID, NULL)
```

Comment: @Daniel Why are you using permission bits and IPC_EXCL to verify existence of the segment? You do not need either. Nevertheless, this is likely not the immediate reason for your problem. You need to provide **minimal** source of the application which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it does work, I just have a minor problem in my code.